# Maximal glmm converges but removing interactions leads to model convergence problems

Tags: convergence, glmm, glmmtmb

I'm running a large negative binomial glmm, with a lot of zeros in my response, using `glmmTMB` in `R`. My model converges when I include all relevant interaction terms and maximal random effects:

```
> summary(full_slopes_zi)
 Family: nbinom2  ( log )
Formula:          
response ~ fixed_effect1 + fixed_effect2 + fixed_effect3 +  
    fixed_effect2 * fixed_effect3 + fixed_effect4 +  
    fixed_effect5 + fixed_effect6 + fixed_effect5 *  
    fixed_effect6 + fixed_effect7 + fixed_effect10 +  
    fixed_effect8 + fixed_effect9 + (1 |  
    random_int1) + (1 | random_int2) + (1 | random_int3) + (0 + fixed_effect7 |  
    random_int1) + (0 + fixed_effect1 | random_int1) + (0 + fixed_effect2 |  
    random_int1) + (0 + fixed_effect4 | random_int1) + (0 + fixed_effect5 |  
    random_int1) + (0 + fixed_effect4 | random_int2) + (0 +  
    fixed_effect5 | random_int2) + (0 + fixed_effect6 | random_int2) +  
    (0 + fixed_effect1 | random_int3) + (0 + fixed_effect2 |  
    random_int3) + (0 + fixed_effect3 | random_int3) + offset(log(observ_effort))
Zero inflation:        ~1
Data: xdata2

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  2996.6   3254.3  -1469.3   2938.6    53428 

Random effects:

Conditional model:
 Groups           Name                        Variance  Std.Dev. 
 random_int1      fixed_effect5               1.606e-11 4.007e-06
 random_int1.1    fixed_effect4               3.581e-10 1.892e-05
 random_int1.2    fixed_effect2               2.275e-11 4.769e-06
 random_int1.3    fixed_effect1               8.019e-13 8.955e-07
 random_int1.4    fixed_effect7               7.697e-26 2.774e-13
 random_int1.5    (Intercept)                 3.263e-01 5.712e-01
 random_int3      fixed_effect3               1.652e-01 4.065e-01
 random_int3.1    fixed_effect2               7.131e-10 2.670e-05
 random_int3.2    fixed_effect1               1.366e-09 3.696e-05
 random_int2      fixed_effect6               8.514e-01 9.227e-01
 random_int2.1    fixed_effect5               4.410e-02 2.100e-01
 random_int2.2    fixed_effect4               6.817e-08 2.611e-04
 random_int3.3    (Intercept)                 8.465e-01 9.201e-01
 random_int2.3    (Intercept)                 1.749e-01 4.182e-01
Number of obs: 53457, groups:  random_int1, 650; random_int3, 26; random_int2, 26

Overdispersion parameter for nbinom2 family (): 0.0197 

Conditional model:
                                    Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                       -10.36447    0.37938 -27.320  < 2e-16 ***
fixed_effect1                       0.05760    0.21806   0.264  0.79166    
fixed_effect2                      -0.75317    0.23669  -3.182  0.00146 ** 
fixed_effect3                      -1.83244    0.43510  -4.211 2.54e-05 ***
fixed_effect4                      -0.38457    0.36155  -1.064  0.28749    
fixed_effect5                       0.60046    0.39544   1.518  0.12890    
fixed_effect6                      -1.16721    0.71922  -1.623  0.10461    
fixed_effect7                       0.59639    0.06273   9.507  < 2e-16 ***
fixed_effect10                      0.91744    0.32895   2.789  0.00529 ** 
fixed_effect8                      -0.70451    0.33839  -2.082  0.03735 *  
fixed_effect9                      -0.32665    0.31686  -1.031  0.30258    
fixed_effect2:fixed_effect3         0.21954    0.38059   0.577  0.56405    
fixed_effect5:fixed_effect6         0.55986    0.66861   0.837  0.40240    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Zero-inflation model:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)   -15.76    3352.47  -0.005    0.996
```

However, when trying to reduce the model, starting by removing the interaction terms one by one, such as removing the interaction between `fixed_effect2:fixed_effect3` or the interaction between `fixed_effect5:fixed_effect6`:

```
Formula:          
 response ~ fixed_effect1 + fixed_effect2 + fixed_effect3 +  
    fixed_effect4 + fixed_effect5 + fixed_effect6 +  
    fixed_effect7 + fixed_effect10 + fixed_effect8 +  
    fixed_effect9 + fixed_effect5 * fixed_effect6 +  
    (1 | random_int1) + (1 | random_int2) + (1 | random_int3) + (0 + fixed_effect7 |  
    random_int1) + (0 + fixed_effect1 | random_int1) + (0 + fixed_effect2 |  
    random_int1) + (0 + fixed_effect4 | random_int1) + (0 + fixed_effect5 |  
    random_int1) + (0 + fixed_effect4 | random_int2) + (0 +  
    fixed_effect5 | random_int2) + (0 + fixed_effect6 | random_int2) +  
    (0 + fixed_effect1 | random_int3) + (0 + fixed_effect2 |  
    random_int3) + (0 + fixed_effect3 | random_int3) + offset(log(observ_effort))
Zero inflation:        ~1
Data: xdata2
```

I end up with a lack of convergence:

```
Warning messages:
1: In fitTMB(TMBStruc) :
  Model convergence problem; non-positive-definite Hessian matrix. See vignette('troubleshooting')
2: In fitTMB(TMBStruc) :
  Model convergence problem; singular convergence (7). See vignette('troubleshooting')
```

What is a plausible explanation for this, and what might be some potential solutions to this lack of convergence? Is this model simply too complicated? If so, I would have expected the lack of convergence to occur **with** the interaction terms, but that's not the case. I also feel like this isn't an issue of complete separation, because in that case, again I would expect the lack of convergence to occur in the maximal model as well.

Any input is much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: While this has a lot of code and software output, I think there's a statistical question about the underlying model (and not the mechanics of R), so I voted to leave this open.